# Zend Framework - redirect without echo before doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, header

The code below **DOESN'T** redirect:

```
return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('/customer/');
```

but this one **DOES** redirect:

```
echo 'redirect';
return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('/customer/');
```

Any ideas? They both work on my localhost but only the second works on my client's machine.
I could add echo 'something' before every redirect call but not sure why it works that way.

Comment: Sounds kind of odd. Is there something different about the clients setup?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't redirect"? Once we know that we may have some clues where it actually fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try once like this :

```
$this->_redirect("/customer/");
```

It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should redirect using...

`$this->_redirect('/customer/', array('exit' => true, 'code' => 301));`

Comment: why would this be preferred over the redirector helper? I mean the defaults for the redirector helper are  exit = true code = 302.

Comment: this is just the way that I've always redirected in ZF and I've never had any issues